# Replace variables with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Is it good approach to replace variables with gulp-replace in `src` directory ?

I have `src` and `build` directories. Within `src` I am writing es6 JS code which should be compiled and minified into `build` directory.

And in `src` directory I have angular config file.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'HomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/BUILD_DIR/app/partials/home.html'
    })
```

During the building process gulp-replace will replace BUILD_DIR var in all files with appropriate directory name, which is `build` in our case.

Is it okay to write such variables in your uncompiled js code ? If not, how to do with it in another way ?

Comment: Not really. The file defining the routes should be in the build directory, too. So there is no point in changing the paths.

Comment: This file in the build dir too. But already with replaced BUILD_DIR.

Comment: One question though... do you test your code from the src directory? It'd be better to run a gulp watch and always push to the build/dest directory, so that there is no need for the replace in the first place.

Comment: It works exactly in this way. So, essentially, in the browser I am working with the code from build dir. In src I just write code.

Comment: oops, I'm here again. Please if my answer below is cool with u, can u mark it as accepted? The question shows 1 answer, and none accepted, so I opened it, forgetting I'd answered it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok, as long as you are sure there will be no side-effects (you mentioned in ALL files, and that looks risky to me). It's better you list out the files in which you want this replacement done, to be sure it doesn't go replacing stuff you don't want. e.g.

```
gulp.task('replace', function() {
    var required_files = [
        '/src/js/app.js',
        '/src/js/controllers.js'
    ];
    return gulp.src(required_files, {base: '/src'})
         .pipe(Useref())//replacements here
         .pipe(gulp.dest('/build'));
});
```

instead of

```
gulp.task('replace', function() {
    return gulp.src('/src/*.*')
         .pipe(Useref())//replacements here
         .pipe(gulp.dest('/build'));
});
```

Comment: Yep, we have a list all files to replace.

Comment: What does the Useref() do?

Comment: @Notflip You can read more about it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref